# Give a hex color to a string so that a string similar to another string will get a similar color

Tags: python-3.x, hash, colors, lsh

I have a list of multiple strings,
I want to get a hex color (like hash) for each string so that similar string will get similar colors.

Example:

- "read register 1" -> #242fff
- "read register 2" -> #242fa5
- "print hello" -> #990000
- "read reg 2" -> #245fb0
- "print hello world" -> #990033

(I will use it to color excel rows, so HSV will not fit this question...)

Any ideas anyone?

thanks!